# How to call a function if the value entered in a woocommerce field changes

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a WordPress website that uses WooCommerce. I am very inexperienced with WooCommerce.

On the checkout page, under billing details, the user has to fill in their first and last name, as well as their email address.

I need to call a function if the data in any of these 3 fields have changed. In this function I need to check if all 3 fields have been completed, then I need to send the info to the server.

How do I connect to the "onchange" event for these 3 fields?

I have tried using "change_woocommerce_field_markup" to add an HTML element that can trigger an event, but no luck so far.

I tried adding the following to the javascript that runs on the page, but the event is never triggered:

```
var email_field = $('#billing_email')
email_field.on('change', function () {
    console.log("email changed");
});
```

I tried using woocommerce_form_field_ to filter on the fields, but I can't get it to work, and I can't find a clear example of how to do it.

Can someone please show me how to connect a function to the change event for the First Name, Last Name, and Email billing fields?
Will you also please show me how to get the data entered into the fields?

Comment: that code looks ok, except `'billing_email'` as a selector isn't going to select anything. I assume you meant either `'.billing_email'` (if it's a class) or `'#billing_email'` (if it's an ID)

Comment: You can also try 
`$("#billing_email").on('keyup', function(){
console.log(this.value);
})`

or

`
$(".billing_email").on('keyup', function(){
console.log(this.value);
});`

Comment: @RobinZigmond you're right. It should have been '#billing_email' (I fixed it in the question). I tried it with the # (i.e. '#billing_email') but the event unfortunately still didn't trigger

Comment: @ImranKhan `.on('keyup'` also didn't trigger

Comment: You can try this `<input type="text" onkeyup="handleChange(this)">` and then define this function within `<script> function handleChange(el) {console.log($(el.val());)} </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `$('#billing_email')` wasn't working was because the JavaScript was queued in the page header, before WooCommerce has generated the HTML for the page. I fixed it by queueing the JavaScript in the page footer by using

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_php_function_that_enqueues_javascript');
```

in the PHP backend.